# Скругление краев фигуры на изображении

Tags: opencv

К примеру, есть изображение с одним каналом на котором находится некая геометрическая фигура, например квадрат (фигура представлена пикселями со значением 255). Необходимо скруглить ее углы. В качестве решения я использовал комбинации эрозии и наращивания с квадратным и элиптическим ядрами, что-то вроде:

```cpp
  cv::erode(alfaChannel,
            alfaChannel,
            cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, {9, 9}),
            {-1, -1},
            2);
  cv::dilate(alfaChannel,
             alfaChannel,
             cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, {7, 7}),
             {-1, -1},
             2);
```

И хоть эта операция действительно скругляет углы, однако проблема в том, что таким образом я воздействую на все изображение целиком и рискую потерять важную информацию на нем (к примеру если там присутствуют линии шириной меньше ядра `erode`). Не подскажите, как еще можно реализовать подобную операцию?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о том, что нужно обнаружить углы и выполнить сглаживание только поблизости от них, то можно воспользоваться [детектором углов Харриса или Shi-Tomasi](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d97/tutorial_table_of_content_features2d.html).

Когда области углов определены, они выбираются в качестве ROI и производится описанное ВАми морфологическое сглаживание.

Comment: весьма интересно, но тут сразу возникает проблема: если применять описанное мной выше преобразование к участку изображения, то могут появиться сдвигив на границах этого участка (так как за пределами участка мы ничего меняли, а в пределах из-за эрозии и наращивания мы можем получить область, которая больше или меньше изначальной)

Comment: Ещё есть такой вариант, если про фон картинки хорошо известно - искать особенность в виде квадрата, угол которого заполнен квадратом другого цвет - собственно, буква `Г`, и заменять его на скругленный фрагмент под таким же углом

Comment: Без искажений в любом случае не обойдется. Можно попробовать плавное сопряжение - обработать большой квадрат сглаживанием с малым размером ядра, вывести. Потом квадрат поменьше - с ядром побольше и т.д.